# I need Wordpress permalink structure in core php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

i need same permalink structure which is in wordpress like that :

`http://example.com/wordpress/2015/08/13/sample-post/`

I developed blogging in custom php

suppose any blog in `year` say 2015 `month` say `08(august)` and blog name say `apple`

then my permalink structure like that :

`http://example.com/2015/08/apple/`

right now my Url is as below:

http://example.com/view-blog.php?bid=19

where `bid` means blog id

can anybody help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?bid=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?bid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?bid=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?bid=$2 [L,QSA]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

for more details..read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963051/i-want-to-remove-question-mark-php-extension-from-the-url-using-htaccess)

Comment: your welcome...but do one thing..before asking on SO, try to search on google..i just used this code in my site via google then so so please..ty

Comment: The answer you gave worked for me but if i want to make my url should be rewritten in this format http://blog.example.com/2015/08/travel/what-is-blog so please help me and be specific so it becomes a bit easy