# I have to remove ".php",''?id","?another_id" from url in php by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I used this link [I want to remove question mark & .php extension from the url using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963051/i-want-to-remove-question-mark-php-extension-from-the-url-using-htaccess) to remove ".php" and "?id".
But  what to be done if i have "?another_id" in url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score -1):

Put this code in your .htaccess file it will remove .php

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`